# Is Objective-J essentially JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objective-j

I've been stumbling upon Objective-J. It should be a superset of JavaScript ... but how's that possible without a browser plugin or some addon? How can they drive around the syntax of JavaScript and make it look like Objective-C code? I mean... COOL... but I don't get it ;) Must I compile that Objective-J code before it goes to the browser?

Comment: Objective-J is a superset of JavaScript: JavaScript code is also valid Objective-J code but Objective-J code is not necessarily valid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article on Objective-J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-J):

> Programs written in Objective-J need
>   to be preprocessed before being run by
>   a web browser's JavaScript virtual
>   machine. This step can occur in the
>   web browser at runtime or by a
>   compiler which translates Objective-J
>   programs into pure JavaScript code.
>   The Objective-J compiler is written in
>   JavaScript, consequently deploying
>   Objective-J programs does not require
>   a plugin attached to the web browser.

Answer (score 2):

> “Must I compile that Objective-J code before it goes to the browser?”

[Nope.](http://cappuccino.org/learn/)

All programming languages are written in another programming language. (E.g. Python — or the main implementation, anyway — is written in C.)

Objective-J is written in JavaScript, hence it can run entirely in the browser.